# Meaning of notation for set in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, notation

I am given this set.

[image: set]

However, I am not sure why it is in $\mathbb R^2$. Isn't $\mathbb R^2$ a plane with 2 dimensions (e.g. call them X and Y)? Why am I given only points for one of the dimensions?

I am supposed to answer if this set is open or closed, compact, etc. But this should not be a problem. Problem is for me to picture this set in my mind

What are the points of this set? Are Y-coordinates similar to X-coordinates: (1,1), (1.1, 1.1), (1.00002, 1.00002), etc? Or are Y-coordinates all zero?

Comment: When we refer to elements in a set, we may call them a simple name.  In this case we chose to call an arbitrary element of $\Bbb R^2$ "$x$".  Now... $x$, being an element of $\Bbb R^2$ is itself an ordered pair of real numbers, i.e. $x=(x_1,x_2)$ where $x\in\Bbb R^2, x_1\in\Bbb R, x_2\in\Bbb R$.  Although you may be more familiar with calling the two coordinates $x$ and $y$, a rose by any other name would smell as sweet.  A name is just a name, and we can choose to refer to things in different manners as we so choose.

Comment: Here, $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^2$, according to $x\in\mathbb R^2$ - it might be confusing since it is not specially marked as a vector.

Comment: Variables, like $x$, can be used for many purposes. Sometimes $x$ represents an element of the set $\mathbb{R}$, which means that $x$ is a real number. But in the notation for the set $S$, instead the variable $x$ represents an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which means that $x$ is an ordered pair of real numbers; you can then invent notation for the two numbers in that ordered pair, writing for example $x=(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The set in question is the set of all points in $\Bbb R^2$ whose magnitude is between $1$ and $2$ (including $1$ but excluding $2$).  To picture it, draw yourself a circle of radius $2$ with the origin as the center, and then draw the unit circle as well, and shade the region inbetween the two circles, outside of the smaller circle but inside the larger circle.  The shaded region including the unit circle but excluding the circle of radius $2$ is your set.  The resulting shape is called an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assuming that as the variable is written "$x$" it is the $x$ value in a two dimensional plane.  That was a convention of high school algebra.

In this case they mean that "$x$" is a point in the plane.  Let's rewrite the variable as $\omega$.

So the set is $\{\omega \in \mathbb R^2| 1 \le ||\omega|| < 2\}$

This is just the set:

$\{\omega = (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2| 1 \le ||\omega|| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 2\}$.

However writing out the pairs of coordinates of point ($\omega = (x,y)$) and specifying the norm-value of the point as the square root of the sum of squares of the coordinates is really... no longer necessary.  And, actually.... kind of tedious.

BTW.  This set is all the points on the plane that are between $1$ and $2$ away from the origin.  This is called an anulus and it is a ring shaped.  It's a disc with the inner circle removed.

However it *does* include all the points exactly $1$ away and it *excludes* all the points exactly $2$ away.

==Addendum====

Other comments and answers refer to these points as "vectors".  That's an equivalent and correct way of viewing them.  I'm not sure why but I prefer to think of them as points in a plane.

Either way, this set is all the vectors with magnitude of at least $1$ and less than $2$.  Or equivalently, all points at least $1$ but less than $2$ away from the origin.

Comment: Probably because norm is mainly a concept related to vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $\mathbb{R^2} := \{(x,y)|x,y \in  \mathbb{R}\}$

Now, $S= \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}\mid 1 \leq \Vert x \Vert < 2\}$. We can read this in the following way:

$S$ is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$ whose length varies from 1 to 2 (2 not included!). If one would colour all these points in the cartesian plane, this would look like a circle with radius 2 through the origin, where another circle with radius 1 and through the origin has been removed (so part of a circle disk). The shape is similar to the shape of a CD .